# Polling data in chunk

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like below.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Poll_EDI834_5010]
AS
BEGIN
select
    Header.ST01,
    Header.ST02,
    Header.ST03 ,
    Header.SE02,
    Line.INS01__InsuredIndicator ,
    Line.PER04__CommunicationNumber ,
      Line.PER05_CommunicationNumberQualifier ,
      Line.DMG06_CitizenshipStatusCode ,
         (select Member_Ref.REF01_ReferenceIdentificationQualifier ,Member_Ref.REF02_MemberSupplementalIdentifier
   from EDI834_5010_2000_RefLoop Member_Ref        
   where Member_Ref.Id_Header = Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
   and Member_Ref.Id_Loop2000 = Line.Member_Id         
   for xml auto, elements, type) ,
    (select Member_DTP.DTP01_DateTimeQualifier , Member_DTP.DTP02_DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier , Member_DTP.DTP03_StatusInformationEffectiveDate
   from EDI834_5010_2000DTP Member_DTP        
   where Member_DTP.Header_Id = Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
   and Member_DTP.Member_Id = Line.Member_Id         
   for xml auto, elements, type) ,
   VLine.HD01_MaintenanceTypeCode,
   VLine.HD03_InsuranceLineCode ,
    VLine.N402_ProviderStateCode ,
   VLine.N403_ProviderPostalZoneorZIPCode ,
      (select ClaimDTP.DTP01__DateTimeQualifier , ClaimDTP.DTP02__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier , ClaimDTP.DTP03__StatusInformationEffectiveDate
     from EDI834_5010_2300_DTPLoop ClaimDTP
     where ClaimDTP.Id_Header = Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode
     and ClaimDTP.Id_Loop2000 = Line.Member_Id
     and ClaimDTP.Id_Loop2300 = VLine.Id_Claim
     for xml auto, elements, type)
from EDI834_5010_Header Header 
join EDI834_5010_2000 Line  on Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = Line.Header_Id
join EDI834_5010_2300Loop VLine on Header.BGN02__TransactionSetIdentifierCode = VLine.Id_Header_Id andVLine.Id_Loop2000=Line.Member_Id
for xml auto,ELEMENTS
END
GO
```

Its fetching aroung 100,000 records. I need to get the data in chunks . Like 10000 first then next 10000...what do i need to change in my stored procedure to get the data in chunks.

Comment: Is this MySql or SQL Server? That FOR statement is not valid TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some kind of index, sequence column, or orderable ID column in your data. Let's call that `keyColumn`. Then you need to split the maximum number of potential rows into how many you want for each iteration. I don't know your schema, so let's just use 10000 rows like you said in your question.

Then you need to select as many rows as fall into each iteration and do... whatever it is that you want to do.

```
SELECT @minID = Min(keyColumn) FROM table WHERE condition
SELECT @maxID = Max(keyColumn) FROM table WHERE condition
SELECT @potentialRows = 10000

WHILE @minID < @maxID
BEGIN
    SET @breakID = @minID + @potentialRows
    SELECT columns FROM table WITH (NOLOCK, ...)
    WHERE condition AND keyColumn BETWEEN @minID AND @breakID

    -- Do what you want with the selected rows here...

    SET @minID = @breakID + 1
END
```

If your `keyColumn` values are sparse you will have to alter the potential rows calculation.

Comment: You'll have to post the code and error message; I can't see your screen.